# Where to start learning how to make mobile web applications

Tags: html, css, mobile

Where do I start to learn how to make mobile web apps? I am interested in the design and effects/animations used to make them look somehow native. There must be some difference in the css, html maybe javascript from regular web appplications with regard to screen sizes etc.

I am a Java developer so usually I use templates, but I am fairly experienced with css, html...but I don't feel very updated on mobile web apps.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what mobile operating system you wanna have your app running on

Answer (score 4):

If you want to develop cross platform mobile application using HTML,Javascript then you can try [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). With Phonegap you can create single application which will run on Android,iOS,Blackberry,Bada,Windows,Symbian etc.

To learn android :
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Phonegap can be a good choice as you are familiar with HTML,Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to give a mobile web-app a very close approximation to native behavior and look is to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and even the associated ThemeRoller.  It's all very well documented, and the site also had great resources for learning.

jQuery Mobile is obviously based on jQuery, but is tailored to be consistent yet configurable across mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using some kind of framework.
There are several.

- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch): Very comprehensive. You don't have to worry about writing any HTML or CSS, since the framework generates it. Sencha Touch provides a Java-like pseudo-class structure, and good documentation.
- [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/): Rather basic.
- [JQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/): Somewhat in the middle.
- [The-M-Project](http://the-m-project.net/): Lesser known, but looks promising. Haven't tried it myself.

All of these offer widgets that come with the required CSS/JS for animation and native looks, so no need to worry about that.